# Docker development workflow with node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, livereload, gulp-watch

I'm trying to use docker with a node.js web app i'm working on.

I have familiarized myself with the docker concepts and gotten up and running with the example here: https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/

I get the general process...write a Dockerfile -> Build a docker image -> run it in a VM.

However, it seems impractical to rebuild the image and restart the container every time I change a file.

I currently have a gulp / live-reload setup that works great for development so I was wondering if there was any recommended way of accomplishing something like this with docker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mount the source directory in the container as a volume and use the same gulp/livereload setup that you currently use now. [Here's an example project with this setup](https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/master/03-express-gulp-watch). If you run into port issues with livereload see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265998/how-to-run-livereload-with-gulp-within-a-docker-container).